# Magento How to change product availability text

Tags: product

I have Magento 1.9 with Fortis II theme.
I need to change the "Availability: In stock" text to "Availability: Available. Will be shipped in 3 working days" and the relevant translations.
I have found and changed accordingly all references of these phrase in Mage_Catalog.csv and in translate.csv which should be applied after the core settings, but nothing happened. Searching fo an answer in the forums I found a relevant topic with an answer about core_translation database table. I have searched this table but no reference found.
So, ho am I going to set the availability text as needed?
Further more, there are products that are available in stock, other products with an aailabity of 3 working days, other on 10 and other are available on order. How ca I set all those availability statuses?

Thank you

Comment: Did you clean the translation cache?

Answer (score 4):

- Go to *frontend/**YOUR_PACKAGE**/**YOUR_THEME**/template/catalog/product/view/type/availability/default.phtml*
- Change `Availability: In stock` text to `Availability: Available. Will be shipped in 3 working days`
- For translation, you can use *Inline Translation*

---

- [Inline translation in Magento](http://inchoo.net/magento/inline-translation-in-magento/)
- [How do I enable Magento inline translation feature](https://kb.magenting.com/content/14/71/en/enable-magento-inline-translation-feature.html)

Comment: Thank you. It works (I've tested it although I had to discover that the IP I should enter was the router's IP). Then, all translations for this text must be done through inline translation because nothing else works. The core_translation table has priority over CSVs. Right?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an attribute in the name "availablity" in your magento admin panel. Create it as a dropdown.
2. Set appropriate values for the products and call them in single product view page.

Comment: Thank you but this method requires to edit this attribute for each one product individually and change it manually when needed. Right? And where in the product page will appear? With the additional information? Because it has to function as the original "availability".

Comment: Yes, This requires some phtml edits. You have to add the following code in your view.phtml.

$_product = Mage::registry('current_product');
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
echo $_product->getAvailability();

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to /app/locale/xx_xx where xx_xx is the language folder for which
   the translation is needed e.g. El_Gr for Greek.
2. Find the Mage_catalogue.csv file and edit it with calc of office.org
   or a simple text editor. You may need to download it first with FTP
   and then again upload the edited file (Filezilla is fine for the
   job). Or if your provider has the ability to edit via text editor
   online you don't need to download it (Plesk has this ability)
3. Find the record(s) "in stock", and change
   the translation to whatever you like
4. Refresh cashes

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This requires some phtml edits. You have to add the following code in your view.phtml.

```
$_product = Mage::registry('current_product');
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId()); 
echo $_product->getAvailability();
```

This code will work. Get back to me..

Answer (score 0):

full path:

**/public_html/app/design/frontend/YOURTHEME/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml**

in my case, if have following:

```
<?php if ($this->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
    <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
        <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Places Available') ?></span></p>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('All Booked - Please Contact Us') ?></span></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento does not support multiple custom stock statuses out of the box. You can modify `app/design/frontend/[YOUR_PACKAGE]/[YOUR_THEME]/template/catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml` and replace the text for 'In stock' and 'Out of stock' to obtain 2 custom variations. If you don't have that file in your theme, it will revert to use `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml`, so you will need to copy it to the same folder in your theme by creating it.

If you need more, you need to modify the file above by replacing the conditional statements:

```
<?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
    <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></p>
<?php else: ?>
    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Add a custom attribute and set the value for each product. Then output the value for the custom attribute in place of the stock status code above like:

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('[SOME_ATTRIBUTE_ALIAS]') ?>
```

Alternatively, you could use this popular extension which does the work for you:
[Custom Stock Status](https://amasty.com/custom-stock-status.html)